# Compare-Object Remove-item Need to change output from Compare-Object in order to Remove

Tags: powershell

I got a script that needs to compare files in two folders, if the file only exists in target it has to be removed. I can't get my head around how I should change the output from Compare-Item in order to delete the file. Also in the delete I have to change the output so it includes a * before the _.

The script looks like:

```
$LocalPath = "C:\test5\old"
$localdestination = "C:\test5\New"

$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem -File "*.qvd" $localpath | Foreach-Object { $_.Name -replace "^.*(?=_)", "" }
$Destination = Get-ChildItem -File "*.qvd" $localdestination | Foreach-Object { $_.Name -replace "^.*(?=_)", "" }

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Destination
foreach($c in $compare)
{
Remove-Item
}
```

Comment: Why there is nothing after remove-item is because I don't have anything working for it as posted in the question.

Comment: You could use [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) to compare folders. With the switch /MIR it is able to remove additional files.

Comment: If you like to use Powershell anyway you should remove both the foreach's after the `Get-ChildItem`, use the `$_.BaseName` for the comparison and use `$c.FullName` for the `Remove-Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your rrequirement right you can use the following snippet:

```
$LocalPath = "C:\test5\old"
$localdestination = "C:\test5\New"

$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem -Path $localpath  -File '*.qvd' 
$Destination = Get-ChildItem -Path $localdestination -File '*.qvd' 

$comparisonFileList = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Destination -Property BaseName -PassThru |
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}
foreach ($comparisonFile in $comparisonFileList) {
    Remove-Item -Path $comparisonFile.FullName
}
```

First you create 2 arrays with the "full" information included - no `Foreach-Object` with replacing something. Then you compare one particular property of the items in these 2 arrays. Then you use the list created by this comparison to iterate over it and use another property of the objects you created earlier to remove the files using its FullName.

Comment: The reason I use the Foreach object the way I do, is cause files are renamed after copy in the previous script, therefore I only compare the last part of the name after _. But when it's time to remove the files it has to put out the whole name if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
$LocalPath = "C:\Source\Qlikview Storage\PrivateData\Gemensamma\Qvd_Raw\Maximo7"
$localdestination = "C:\Dest\Qlikview Storage\PrivateData\Gemensamma\Qvd_Raw\Maximo7"

$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem -File "*.qvd" $localpath | Foreach-Object { $_.Name -replace "^.*(?=_)", "" }
$Destination = Get-ChildItem -File "*.qvd" $localdestination | Foreach-Object { $_.Name -replace "^.*(?=_)", "" }

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Destination |
Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}

$comparison = $compare.InputObject

foreach($comp in $comparison)
{
$comparisonfile = "maximo" + $comp
Remove-Item $localdestination\$comparisonfile
}
```

This is the solution I made at last, I took some of your stuff to work forward with Olaf, thank you for the input.